# Popen throws error for 'ps x' command in C++

Tags: c++, unix, popen

I am trying to get list of running process using popen in C++ using below code.

```
  FILE* fp = popen("ps x", "r");

  if (fp == nullptr) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Could not popen");
  }

  std::array<char, 4096> buff;
  std::string output;

  while (fgets(buff.data(), 4096, fp) != nullptr) {
    output += buff.data();
  }

  int status = pclose(fp);
```

In my system the return value of status is 256.

I also tried other unix command like ls, pwd, whoami etc. all works fine. I am getting this error for 'ps x' command only. What I know is that popen initiates a process like "sh -c 'ps x'"

I tried same thing in online compiler which gives output as expected( https://onlinegdb.com/Tl6ftiwek )

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried `ps -x`? Some implementations of POSIX get fussy about dashes in flags.

Comment: Yes I have tried with dash as well

Comment: Does `ps x` work from your terminal shell?

Comment: Yes it does give me expected output from terminal shell

Comment: What UNIX flavor are you using? FreeBSD and Linux return the status value with same semantics as `wait4()`. So you need to use the macros to decode the status. Only a return value of `-1` would indicate an actual error.